# What's wrong with this SwitchOnRebuildSolrCloudSearchIndex index definition?

Tags: solr, indexing, cloud

I'm trying to get a custom index to work on Solr cloud (searchstax) as described by the "Switch SolrCloud indexes section of [this page](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/switch-solr-indexes.html)) on  and I'm getting the error

> "Could not create instance of type:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrCloudSearchIndex.
>   No matching constructor was found."

Any thoughts on what's wrong with this index definition?

```
    <index id="clientname_content_index_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrCloudSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"  >
    <param desc="mainalias">$(id)MainAlias</param>
    <param desc="rebuildalias">$(id)RebuildAlias</param>
    <param desc="collection">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="rebuildcollection">$(id)_temp</param>
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />                  
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/clientnameSolrIndexConfiguration" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="clientname.Solr.Search.ExcludePathsItemCrawler, clientname.Solr.Search">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
            <ExcludeItemsList hint="list">
                <FileRepository>/sitecore/media library/Files/Corporate/Publications/File_Repository</FileRepository>
            </ExcludeItemsList>                         
        </crawler>
    </locations>
    <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
    <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>
```

Platform is Sitecore 9.2 on Azure apps service

Comment: Can you please share your config for contentSearch/indexConfigurations/clientnameSolrIndexConfiguration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `name` param xml element.

Documentation says:

> The configuration is similar to what is described for Solr, except for this:

And then that part of your configuration is added.

You need index configuration with the following parameters:

```
string name,
string mainalias,
string rebuildalias,
string activecollection,
string rebuildcollection,
IIndexPropertyStore propertyStore
```

Just add

```
<param desc="name">index_name</param>
```

as the **FIRST** `<param>` tag before your other parameters.